# Log during Android Unit Test in Intellij gives java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub

Tags: android, unit-testing, intellij-idea

I am currently trying to migrate from Android Studio to Intellij.

The problem arises when I try to run my code through unit tests. A method in the code under test calls Log.e and an exception is thrown in Intellij IDE. The same code runs fine in Android Studio. Probably my project settings may configured incorrectly in Intellij. Any one knows where to look for the problem?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
at android.util.Log.e(Log.java:31)
```

My Intellij command when running the unit test.

```
D:\software\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\java.exe -ea -Didea.test.cyclic.buffer.size=1048576 
"-javaagent:D:\software\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.2.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=4006:D:\software\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.2.2\bin" 
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
-classpath 

"D:\software\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.2.2\lib\idea_rt.jar;
 D:\software\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.2.2\plugins\junit\lib\junit-rt.jar;
 D:\software\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.2.2\plugins\junit\lib\junit5-rt.jar;
 D:\software\Android\sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar;
 D:\software\Android\sdk\platforms\android-28\data\res;
 D:\software\Android\sdk\platforms\android-27\data\res;
 D:\code\android\MyProjectAndroid\myProjectandroidgc\build\intermediates\classes\debug;
 D:\software\Android\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\net.bytebuddy\byte-buddy-agent\1.7.9\a6c65f9da7f467ee1f02ff2841ffd3155aee2fc9\byte-buddy-agent-1.7.9.jar;
 D:\software\Android\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\runner-1.0.2.aar\d44dda11e7de1711127415e572906e3c\jars\classes.jar;
 D:\software\Android\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.objenesis\objenesis\2.6\639033469776fd37c08358c6b92a4761feb2af4b\objenesis-2.6.jar;
 D:\software\Android\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\android.arch.lifecycle\common\1.1.0\edf3f7bfb84a7521d0599efa3b0113a0ee90f85\common-1.1.0.jar;
 D:\software\Android\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.android.support\support-annotations\27.1.1\39ded76b5e1ce1c5b2688e1d25cdc20ecee32007\support-annotations-27.1.1.jar;
 D:\software\Android\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\animated-vector-drawable-27.1.1.aar\87b44b5092008154f1171a969696f102\jars\classes.jar;
 D:\software\Android\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-compat-27.1.1.aar\5e64a504ec19504fa9b2687a61b079c4\jars\classes.jar;
 D:\software\Android\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-compat-27.1.1.aar\5e64a504ec19504fa9b2687a61b079c4\res;
 D:\software\Android\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\net.bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.7.9\51218a01a882c04d0aba8c028179cce488bbcb58\byte-buddy-1.7.9.jar;
 D:\software\Android\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\viewmodel-1.1.0.aar\8d37b7feb2744759cd91b03ad94efb30\jars\classes.jar;
 D:\software\Android\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.mockito\mockito-core\2.15.0\b84bfbbc29cd22c9529409627af6ea2897f4fa85\mockito-core-2.15.0.jar;
 D:\software\Android\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.nhaarman\mockito-kotlin\1.5.0\25faa884f76375f76cdbd6651c4cebcde36d4117\mockito-kotlin-1.5.0.jar;
 D:\software\Android\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.squareup\javawriter\2.1.1\67ff45d9ae02e583d0f9b3432a5ebbe05c30c966\javawriter-2.1.1.jar;
 D:\software\Android\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.github.kotlin-graphics\kotlin-unsigned\v2.1\52408e5d299c5d1fb669188dae56fa5bb37cbc12\kotlin-unsigned-v2.1.jar;
 D:\software\Android\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-vector-drawable-27.1.1.aar\8949c790c8f1bf421289f293aa4e1cc2\jars\classes.jar;
 D:\software\Android\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-core-ui-27.1.1.aar\1c49103dd8f3bd81aa06fd4de90258d6\jars\classes.jar;
 D:\software\Android\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-core-ui-27.1.1.aar\1c49103dd8f3bd81aa06fd4de90258d6\res;
 D:\software\Android\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-core-utils-27.1.1.aar\fb3bae07f3360874234d36f26caa5ebb\jars\classes.jar;
 D:\software\Android\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains\annotations\13.0\919f0dfe192fb4e063e7dacadee7f8bb9a2672a9\annotations-13.0.jar;
 D:\software\Android\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.code.findbugs\jsr305\2.0.1\516c03b21d50a644d538de0f0369c620989cd8f0\jsr305-2.0.1.jar;
 D:\software\Android\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\espresso-core-3.0.2.aar\369dec0c3f47cc8d75f961fddc94d0f7\jars\classes.jar;
 D:\software\Android\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\javax.inject\javax.inject\1\6975da39a7040257bd51d21a231b76c915872d38\javax.inject-1.jar;
 D:\software\Android\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-fragment-27.1.1.aar\0464588052e7fe27a8be9d866a5cd81f\jars\classes.jar;
 D:\software\Android\.gradle\caches\modul:es-2\files-2.1\junit\junit\4.12\2973d150c0dc1fefe998f834810d68f278ea58ec\junit-4.12.jar;
 D:\software\Android\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\runtime-1.1.0.aar\4aa45f99c024430a3ccf7c0e257fb60a\jars\classes.jar;
 D:\software\Android\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.hamcrest\hamcrest-core\1.3\42a25dc3219429f0e5d060061f71acb49bf010a0\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;
 D:\software\Android\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\monitor-1.0.2.aar\94d037806c32cc9e5663a80cfb787b67\jars\classes.jar;
 D:\software\Android\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\2668a362e92dc09e5e5a2ec0e09458ea\res;
 D:\software\Android\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\2668a362e92dc09e5e5a2ec0e09458ea\jars\classes.jar;
 D:\software\Android\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\espresso-idling-resource-3.0.2.aar\3b7ac85279e2aa734ba776a985e5273e\jars\classes.jar;
 D:\software\Android\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-reflect\1.2.30\9758025a415ee400e1f90ff222bcfec247779133\kotlin-reflect-1.2.30.jar;
 D:\software\Android\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib\1.2.30\2dfac33f8b4e92c9dd1422cd286834701a6f6d6\kotlin-stdlib-1.2.30.jar;
 D:\software\Android\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\livedata-core-1.1.0.aar\8c471aa13e8c6e412a4748be6e503cbc\jars\classes.jar;
 D:\software\Android\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.hamcrest\hamcrest-library\1.3\4785a3c21320980282f9f33d0d1264a69040538f\hamcrest-library-1.3.jar;
 D:\software\Android\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.hamcrest\hamcrest-integration\1.3\5de0c73fef18917cd85d0ab70bb23818685e4dfd\hamcrest-integration-1.3.jar;
 D:\software\Android\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\android.arch.core\common\1.1.0\8007981f7d7540d89cd18471b8e5dcd2b4f99167\common-1.1.0.jar;
 D:\software\Android\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib-jdk7\1.2.30\ca12c47fc1e3a7316067b2a51e2f214745ebf8c5\kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.2.30.jar;
 D:\software\Android\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\net.sf.kxml\kxml2\2.3.0\ccbc77a5fd907ef863c29f3596c6f54ffa4e9442\kxml2-2.3.0.jar;
 D:\software\Android\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\runtime-1.1.0.aar\f827adbdf97ad86b4140dcb5e1073a50\jars\classes.jar;
 D:\code\android\MyProjectAndroid\myProjectandroidgc\build\intermediates\sourceFolderJavaResources\test\debug;
 D:\code\android\MyProjectAndroid\myProjectandroidgc\build\intermediates\unitTestConfig\test\debug;
 D:\code\android\MyProjectAndroid\myProjectandroidgc\build\tmp\kotlin-classes\debugUnitTest;
 D:\code\android\MyProjectAndroid\myProjectandroidgc\build\intermediates\sourceFolderJavaResources\debug;
 D:\code\android\MyProjectAndroid\myProjectandroidgc\build\tmp\kotlin-classes\debug;
D:\code\android\MyProjectAndroid\myProjectandroidgc\build\generated\mockable-android-26.default-values.v3.jar"
 com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter 
-ideVersion5 @w@C:\Users\cjf12\AppData\Local\Temp\idea_working_dirs_junit.tmp @C:\Users\cjf12\AppData\Local\Temp\idea_junit.tmp
```

My Android studio command for running the unit test.

```
"D:\software\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java"
-ea
-Didea.test.cyclic.buffer.size=1048576
-Didea.launcher.port=3647
"-Didea.launcher.bin.path=D:\software\Android\Android Studio\bin"
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
-classpath
     "D:\software\Android\Android Studio\lib\idea_rt.jar;
     D:\software\Android\Android Studio\plugins\junit\lib\junit-rt.jar;
     D:\software\Android\Android Studio\plugins\junit\lib\junit5-rt.jar;
     D:\software\Android\sdk\platforms\android-27\data\res;
     D:\code\android\myProjectAndroid\myprojectandroid\build\intermediates\classes\debug;
     D:\code\android\myProjectAndroid\myprojectandroid\build\tmp\kotlin-classes\debug;
     D:\code\android\myProjectAndroid\myprojectandroid\build\generated\res\rs\debug;
     D:\code\android\myProjectAndroid\myprojectandroid\build\generated\res\resValues\debug;
     D:\code\android\myProjectAndroid\myprojectandroid\build\intermediates\unitTestConfig\test\debug;
     D:\code\android\myProjectAndroid\myprojectandroid\build\tmp\kotlin-classes\debugUnitTest;
     D:\code\android\myProjectAndroid\myprojectandroid\build\tmp\kotlin-classes\debugAndroidTest;
     D:\code\android\myProjectAndroid\myprojectandroid\build\generated\res\rs\androidTest\debug;
     D:\code\android\myProjectAndroid\myprojectandroid\build\generated\res\resValues\androidTest\debug;
     D:\software\Android\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\net.bytebuddy\byte-buddy-agent\1.7.9\a6c65f9da7f467ee1f02ff2841ffd3155aee2fc9\byte-buddy-agent-1.7.9.jar;
     D:\software\Android\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.objenesis\objenesis\2.6\639033469776fd37c08358c6b92a4761feb2af4b\objenesis-2.6.jar;
     D:\software\Android\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\android.arch.lifecycle\common\1.1.0\edf3f7bfb84a7521d0599efa3b0113a0ee90f85\common-1.1.0.jar;
     D:\software\Android\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.android.support\support-annotations\27.1.1\39ded76b5e1ce1c5b2688e1d25cdc20ecee32007\support-annotations-27.1.1.jar;
     D:\software\Android\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\animated-vector-drawable-27.1.1.aar\87b44b5092008154f1171a969696f102\jars\classes.jar;
     D:\software\Android\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-compat-27.1.1.aar\5e64a504ec19504fa9b2687a61b079c4\jars\classes.jar;
     D:\software\Android\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-compat-27.1.1.aar\5e64a504ec19504fa9b2687a61b079c4\res;
     D:\software\Android\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\net.bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.7.9\51218a01a882c04d0aba8c028179cce488bbcb58\byte-buddy-1.7.9.jar;
     D:\software\Android\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\viewmodel-1.1.0.aar\8d37b7feb2744759cd91b03ad94efb30\jars\classes.jar;
     D:\software\Android\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.mockito\mockito-core\2.15.0\b84bfbbc29cd22c9529409627af6ea2897f4fa85\mockito-core-2.15.0.jar;
     D:\software\Android\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.nhaarman\mockito-kotlin\1.5.0\25faa884f76375f76cdbd6651c4cebcde36d4117\mockito-kotlin-1.5.0.jar;
     D:\software\Android\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.github.kotlin-graphics\kotlin-unsigned\v2.1\52408e5d299c5d1fb669188dae56fa5bb37cbc12\kotlin-unsigned-v2.1.jar;
     D:\software\Android\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-vector-drawable-27.1.1.aar\8949c790c8f1bf421289f293aa4e1cc2\jars\classes.jar;
     D:\software\Android\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-core-ui-27.1.1.aar\1c49103dd8f3bd81aa06fd4de90258d6\jars\classes.jar;
     D:\software\Android\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-core-ui-27.1.1.aar\1c49103dd8f3bd81aa06fd4de90258d6\res;
     D:\software\Android\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-core-utils-27.1.1.aar\fb3bae07f3360874234d36f26caa5ebb\jars\classes.jar;
     D:\software\Android\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains\annotations\13.0\919f0dfe192fb4e063e7dacadee7f8bb9a2672a9\annotations-13.0.jar;
     D:\software\Android\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-fragment-27.1.1.aar\0464588052e7fe27a8be9d866a5cd81f\jars\classes.jar;
     D:\software\Android\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\junit\junit\4.12\2973d150c0dc1fefe998f834810d68f278ea58ec\junit-4.12.jar;
     D:\software\Android\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\runtime-1.1.0.aar\4aa45f99c024430a3ccf7c0e257fb60a\jars\classes.jar;
     D:\software\Android\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.hamcrest\hamcrest-core\1.3\42a25dc3219429f0e5d060061f71acb49bf010a0\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;
     D:\software\Android\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\2668a362e92dc09e5e5a2ec0e09458ea\res;
     D:\software\Android\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\2668a362e92dc09e5e5a2ec0e09458ea\jars\classes.jar;
     D:\software\Android\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-reflect\1.2.30\9758025a415ee400e1f90ff222bcfec247779133\kotlin-reflect-1.2.30.jar;
     D:\software\Android\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib\1.2.30\2dfac33f8b4e92c9dd1422cd286834701a6f6d6\kotlin-stdlib-1.2.30.jar;
     D:\software\Android\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\livedata-core-1.1.0.aar\8c471aa13e8c6e412a4748be6e503cbc\jars\classes.jar;
     D:\software\Android\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\android.arch.core\common\1.1.0\8007981f7d7540d89cd18471b8e5dcd2b4f99167\common-1.1.0.jar;
     D:\software\Android\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib-jdk7\1.2.30\ca12c47fc1e3a7316067b2a51e2f214745ebf8c5\kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.2.30.jar;
     D:\software\Android\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\runtime-1.1.0.aar\f827adbdf97ad86b4140dcb5e1073a50\jars\classes.jar;
     D:\code\android\myProjectAndroid\myprojectandroid\build\intermediates\sourceFolderJavaResources\test\debug;
     D:\code\android\myProjectAndroid\myprojectandroid\build\intermediates\sourceFolderJavaResources\debug;
     D:\code\android\myProjectAndroid\myprojectandroid\build\generated\mockable-android-27.default-values.v3.jar"
com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2
com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter
-ideVersion5
@w@C:\Users\cjf12\AppData\Local\Temp\idea_working_dirs_junit.tmp
@C:\Users\cjf12\AppData\Local\Temp\idea_junit.tmp
-socket3646
```

This is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.mycompany.myproject"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/java'
        test.java.srcDirs += 'src/test/java'
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            testCoverageEnabled true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    testOptions {
        unitTests {
            includeAndroidResources = true
            returnDefaultValues = true
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.kotlin-graphics:kotlin-unsigned:v2.1'

    // Required -- JUnit 4 framework
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    // Optional -- Mockito framework
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.15.0'
    testImplementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    testImplementation "com.nhaarman:mockito-kotlin:1.5.0"
    testImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'com.github.kotlin-graphics:kotlin-unsigned:v2.1'

    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1- Add this to your build.gradle**

```
testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:${mockitoVersion}"
testImplementation "org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:${powerMockVersion}"
```

[Checkout the supported versions of Mockito and PowerMock](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito#supported-versions)

For example if you use `v1.9.5` for Mockito use `v1.6.6` for PowerMock

**2- Annotate your test class with this**

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTesting(Log.class)
public class YourTestClass {
```

And your test cases should run now.

Also as @Code-Apprentice said if you want to log something inside the testing class use `System.out.println()`. Do not use Android dependencies for testing, this just to bypass the logs inside the methods you are unit testing.

**UPDATE**

Adding this to your `build.gradle` will also help with no need for PowerMock (not highly recommend). Please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39171844/7330512)

```
android { 
     //... 
     testOptions { 
          unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true 
     }
 }
```

Comment: The Log.e is in the code under test, not in the test class. I will try using power mock as a work around. But I think there is a solution which use the original runner without mocking, based on the fact that the same project runs fine in Android studio.

Comment: You can but it is not the best practice as it will return the default values for all android dependencies. It is better to mock them.
Refer to the "updated" section in the answer

Comment: You reminded me of it. Now I check the build.gradle, it includes this clause already. And both the Intellij and Android Studio use the same build.gradle file. I updated my question with the build.gradle file.

Comment: Using v1.7.1 of powermock, it's PrepareForTest and not PrepareForTesting

Answer (score 3):

When running unit tests, no methods from the Android API are available. The error "java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!" occurs when you try to call any of these functions, including `Log.e()`. If you need output, use the standard `System.out.println()` instead. Or use the IntelliJ debugger.

Comment: The same project, when opened in Android Studio, can run this method successfully, without throwing the exception.